# How to compile and use make command to install this certain program/tool?

Tags: debian, make

**Introduction**

I'm following through the book "*Learning linux binary Analysis*". This book uses 32 bit code examples. The book wants me to either use a tool called *Eresi* or his own tool called *Quenya* for a RET_REL injection (relocatable code injection).

For the sake of following the book, and as well as no tutorials being on Eresi, i've decided to download his tool, here is a link to the file: [Quenya_32bit.tgz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9zd4jp9igy5iv6/quenya_32bit.tgz?dl=0)

**Source**

```
This README file is very limited since Quenya was never meant to be  released.
Although Quenya is very functional, it is mostly available for research purposes
into the ELF format, and what it means to hack ELF binaries, and process images.
To compile:

cd libptrace;
./configure; make

cd libdasm-1.5; make

Then in top directory of quenya type make.

./quenya

Once at command prompt type help

elfmaster [at] bitlackeys [dot] org
```

When unpackaged in the directory there is a 'README' file which tells how to install and configure to be able to use the tool. To access the directories shown in the instructions i had to make sure to use chmod so I was able to access them.

**The problem**

I can't seem to get the executable ./quenya in the top directory. When running 'make' in libptrace and as well as in libdasm-1.5 im getting wimplicit function declarations. AS well as this when i perform the last instruction of typing make in the top directory i recieve this fatal error:

> fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory

I'm just wondering if anyone else can give it a try making and see if it works on their system, or does anyone know the solution to help me fix this and install the tool?  This is probably a basic question. The book uses 32 bit examples, so i'm guessing it could be a problem with me making it on a 64 bit system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For other interested readers wary of downloading a tarball from Dropbox, the code is also available from the Internet Archive, [archived from the original site](http://web.archive.org/web/20161026134517/http://bitlackeys.org/projects/quenya_32bit.tgz).)

I don’t think there should be any problem building and running this on a 64-bit system. To fix your error, you need to install `libncurses5-dev`; with that installed,

```
make -C libdasm-1.5
make
```

works for me.